# ORDER BY CASE WHEN ... ELSE ... END in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have my `ORDER BY` clause as following:

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN boolean_column is true  THEN text_column END ASC,
         CASE WHEN boolean_column is false THEN text_column END DESC
```

Is it somehow possible to replace the second `CASE` in an `ELSE`? It feels odd to have two conditions instead of a regular `if else/when else` as you normally would do.

Comment: not too trivial - because you use ascending in first case and descending in other

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this trick to shorten the logic:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN boolean_column THEN text_column END) ASC,
         text_column DESC
```

It is still two `order by` keys though.

Answer (score 4):

If the type of text_column is numeric. you can try this.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN boolean_column is true THEN text_column 
              ELSE -1 * text_column END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the sorting at first, getting the position of each record, and then choose the sorting direction

```
WITH rows_with_positions AS (
    SELECT
        boolean_column,
        text_column,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY text_column) AS position,
        .. 
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT text_column, ..
FROM rows_with_positions
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN boolean_column
        THEN position
        ELSE -1 * position
        END
    ASC
```